# Dynamically add more fields consists of 2 dynamic dropdown (category dropdown and product dropdown) and one input box to enter price

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I want to populate two dropdowns dynamically which is fetched from database and one input box
First dropdown: Populate category
Second Dropdown: According to category all products are populate in product dropdown
Input Box: Enter price

These three fields were dynamically added by add more with jQuery
[image: sample]

Comment: there are so many answers on the stackoverflow first search it on google

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: According to category I get related values in product dropdown. But How can I Add these 3 fields by clicking on Add more link and these dropdowns have there IDs by which I show data in another dropdown. If I add new fields then how can I change there IDs

Comment: please be clear ,what's your question exactly ,where is your code ,what's the problem /issue you face?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="">
    Category :
    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value=''>------- Select --------</option>
        <?php 
        $sql = "select * from `categories`";
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row->cat_id."'>".$row->cat_name."</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    Products :
    <select name="products" id="products"><option>------- Select --------</option></select>
</div>


<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$("#category").change(function() {
    var product_id = $(this).val();
    if(product_id != "") {
        $.ajax({
            url:"get-products.php",
            data:{c_id:product_id},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(response) {
                var resp = $.trim(response);
                $("#products").html(resp);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#products").html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
    }
}); }); </script>
```

Comment: this works fine but now I want to create 'add more' link  which adds more dropdowns divs in one form